# Is picture library slideshow webpart down?

Tags: 2013, web-part, picture-library

I am using sharepoint 2013 , is this app not working everywhere? in my site wherever i have applied this , it is not working , ie not playing automatically. is the app affected?

Comment: Is it Sharepoint 2013 on premise or Sharepoint Online? If on premise, have you applied any update or made any changes into masterpages? Have you tried contacting Microsoft Support? Do you have any background information that could help?

Comment: pls mark my answer if I have solved your problem

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue too. There was problem with Pictures library this month due to updates by MS. Check service messages in admin center below are details. It says service restored but there are still issues reported by people.

SP101452 - Picture Library Slideshow not displaying images

Status:Service restored

User impact:Users may have been unable to view images within a Picture Library Slideshow web part.

Latest message:Title: Picture Library Slideshow not displaying images

Updated:2017-05-17 04:16 (UTC)

**[Update]**

Other problem causing this issue may be CDN policy by MS you need to enable CDN for you picture library. you can execute below script with Powershell

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -Url sitename-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $creds

Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private

Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private -Enable $true 
Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private 
Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Private -OriginUrl */libname

#Reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790767.aspx
```

Comment: Can you please refer me the site where i can go through the status?

Comment: You can see this in admin center of your portal or contact Microsoft for that

Answer (score 2):

Well, the feature of Picture Library Slideshow Web Part for  automatically doing slideshow based on certain time duration will not be working for your Picture Library until CDN is enabled. Find [Official Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4021555/non-cdn-enabled-sharepoint-picture-library-slideshow-web-part-no-longe)

So to solve the existing Issue for your app, Please ask your O365 tenant Admin to enable CDN.

Action Plan: Use Powershell commands to enable CDN by following this [MS Article](https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release)

Answer (score -1):

Things to be aware about picture library. you can look at this for your reference.
http://sharepointmaven.com/add-slideshow-sharepoint-site/

you can also read each and every property of slideshow webpart from this reference
 http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5742

Comment: Both of these links direct to relatively long external blog posts, which could one day not be available. Could you extract the key points from the sources you mentioned and edit them to your answer?

Comment: Like few days back it was working , last year when i used the app it used to work, same thing i was trying again but this time the app doesnt work anymore, do i need to download anything as an admin ?

Comment: I don't think you are replying the question, he already had and it's not working anymore, what could be the issue.