# Help needed - picture library slideshow web part - photos not changing on time period

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, picture

I'm using sharepoint 2013 for our works teamsite.  On the home page I use the web part to display staff photos from a picture library.  This has worked in the past fine - updating every 5 seconds.  When the page comes up it displays a random photo from the library but it no longer updates the photo after the time period. If navigating away from the page and back again a different photo does display. Settings for the web part are Duration:   5 seconds, Library view - All pictures, display mode - random, Display with: Title and description to right, fixed ht 200, fixed width 300,

I did change which picture library was used sometime back but it worked ok and have reverted to old versions to double check and that no longer works.

I've deleted the web part and recreated.  I created a new picture library and copied pictures across in case there was something wrong with the library. I've tried IE, Edge and chrome.  Have run out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: screenshot of settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the feature of Picture Library Slideshow Web Part for automatically doing slideshow based on certain time duration will not be working for your Picture Library until CDN is enabled. Find [Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4021555/non-cdn-enabled-sharepoint-picture-library-slideshow-web-part-no-longe)

So to solve the existing Issue for your app, Please ask your O365 tenant Admin to enable CDN.

Action Plan: Use Powershell commands to enable CDN by following this [MS Article](https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release)

**[My Duplicate Answer for another [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215917/is-picture-library-slideshow-webpart-down) ]**

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue too. There was problem with Pictures library this month due to updates by MS. Check service messages in admin center below are details. It says service restored but there are still issues reported by people.

SP101452 - Picture Library Slideshow not displaying images

Status:Service restored

User impact:Users may have been unable to view images within a Picture Library Slideshow web part.

Latest message:Title: Picture Library Slideshow not displaying images

Updated:2017-05-17 04:16 (UTC)

**[Update]**

Other problem causing this issue may be CDN policy by MS you need to enable CDN for you picture library. you can execute below script with Powershell

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -Url sitename-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $creds

Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private

Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private -Enable $true 
Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private 
Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Private -OriginUrl */libname

#Reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790767.aspx
```

Comment: Finally got our IT support to look at the CDN enabling and all now working again and my pictures changing perfectly.  

For anyone else having this problem as far as I know the office-365/sharepoint steps came down to
1.Connect to SharePoint Online tenant with PowerShell
1.1.Connect-SPOService -Url https://sitename-admin.sharepoint.com
2.Enable CDN in the tenant for private 
2.1.Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType  Private -Enable $true
2.2.Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType  Private
3.Add CDN origin for picture library
3.1.Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private -OriginUrl */libname